# SVM with too many observations, any library or solution?

Tags: r, classification, svm

In R Studio I have a database with 77,000 rows and 50 columns, I divide the observations into train and test, and the train table is left with 59,000 observations, I am making the SVM model, I am now calculating with the tune function which parameters are the best using the radial kernel, and it never runs, it is always loaded, it could be because of the number of rows I have, does anyone know of a library or solution for this?

```
set.seed(123)
tune_r = tune.svm(MH7A~., data=train, kernel="radial",
                cost = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 5, 10),
                gamma = c(0.01, 0.1, 1, 5))
summary(tune_r)
```

Comment: Don't just speculate -- actually try it with say 10% of the data rows (selected at random) to make sure it *isn't* something other than the number of rows.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.